# Is it bad to remove ID from views?

Tags: android, android-layout

If you have a layout that has a bunch of views that won't be changed during runtime, for example a TextView used as a label, is it proper to remove the ID from it, or to label it like a view that you would use?

What about layouts? If I have a bunch or table rows in a table, should each have a unique ID or should I clear the field?

It seems to me like it removes a lot of clutter if I clear the IDs if views that I won't be changing but I don't want to do that if it's bad practice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to define an id for an UI component if you want to reference this component later from your program code (e.g. `findViewById(R.id.my_textview)` ).

Because you said the views won't change during runtime you don't have to define an id for every view.

It can even help you if you don't define an id, because it keeps the auto complete function of your IDE clean. If you have a lot of layouts (which contain lots of ui elements) and you define an id for each component then you will have a nearly endless list of component ids at the end.

Comment: Thanks! That was my reasoning behind clearing the ID field. I really like the auto complete feature of eclipse, but I don't like it when it's filled with lots of TextViewXX items that I'll never use. I just didn't know if it was bad to clear them.

Answer (score 1):

@matt: if your are using canvas to draw the views and set layouts then id is not necessary from my knowledge and I never used id fro  and I think its not bad practise.